# MySQL - How to automatically log selects from table

Tags: mysql, triggers, logging

currently I can log user insertions and updates on my tables to a table called Log. But I can't find how to enable triggers or something to also do it with selects.

Comment: There are no `SELECT` triggers.

Comment: @ypercube yeah thats why I'm looking for some other way to find it, gonna try the mysql proxy

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into mysql proxy - you can log everything that passes into mysql, modify it, etc.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

use a tool to read the mysql log. is the simpliest and elegant way to track  mysql log.